# how to set a property of a static resource via a binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In the XAML fragment below, ItemsSource is set correctly for "testGrid" but for "testGridResource" it is null.  How do I set the ItemsSource of the grid defined as a resource via a binding?  More generally,  how do I set a property of an object defined as a static resource via a binding (I am only using datagrid as an example in my app I am using other objects)?

```
<Window x:Class="StackedBarTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="root">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataGrid x:Key="testGridResource" ItemsSource="{Binding LoadStatistics, ElementName=root}"></DataGrid>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <DataGrid x:Name="testGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding LoadStatistics, ElementName=root}"></DataGrid>
```

Comment: where are you using testGridResource? You need to set DataContext of the enclosing xaml element.

Comment: @Tilak  DataContext is set in the constructor of the class.  Its the same datacontext being used by testGrid.  Also, I am binding to a property of a named element (root).

Comment: Where are you using the resource you are creating named `testGridResource` ?

Comment: `Binding` will be picked based on the usage of this resource.

Comment: @RV1987 In this dummy app I am not using testGridResource. I just look at ItemsSource in the click handler of a button and observe that it is null. Now, this wont make sense but since you asked I'll tell you.  In my question I said I am only using the grid as an example.  In my app I am using an Infragistics component called GroupBy.  GroupBy has an ItemsSource property just like DataGrid and I am using it in exactly the way I showed in my code fragment above.  The GroupBy object is then used used as an ItemsSource for a Chart object.

Comment: In your Output window, does it show any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the answer is this:  If a resource is not used in xaml it is not parsed so properties that are targets of bindings will appear null.  So the bindings that were posted above are all correct however since the resource was never used in xaml it was never parsed, thus the ItemSource appeared null.

See this link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7aed2cbf-1980-4f3d-8354-83227662f428

Answer (score 0):

See If this helps to answer your question: [Binding to static properties](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/28/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-9-binding-to-static-properties/)

Comment: I think that article discusses the difference between static binding and dynamic binding.  In any case, the solution is not obvious to me.  Can you kindly tell me which part of the article addresses the question I asked?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to binf your DataGrid to testGridResource, if so this should work

```
<DataGrid x:Name="testGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource testGridResource}}">
```

Not sure if this is what your wanting

Maybe this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="testGridResource" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LoadStatistics, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}
```

Comment: No that is not what I want to do - I want to bind the ItemsSource of "testGridResource" to a property named LoadStatistics that exists on the window class (i.e. "root").

Comment: my appoligies - the code you show is actually functional but it does not answer my question.  Please see the link in the answer.